# Github API Authentication not allowing 5k requests per hour (using curl)

Tags: api, rest, github, curl, github-api

I'm attempting to locate all the repositories that use javascript. When I use this line in terminal as found in the guide

`$ curl -i -u your_username https://api.github.com/users/octocat`

and then use my token as a password, I correctly get an increased rate limit

```
X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4999
```

However when I go to do a search, I still only get a few results (definitely less than 100, much less 5000)

```
curl  -H "Accept:applicationvnd.github.v3.text-match+json" "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:js&sort=stars&order=desc"
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The rate limit for the API says how many individual HTTP requests you can make to the REST API.  It doesn't indicate the number of responses you'll get from a request.

Typically, the GitHub REST API returns items in pages of 100, and you'll need to make multiple requests if you want more.  However, it's also possible that the request you made just doesn't have more responses than that.  As a guess, it may be that the language should be "javascript" instead of "js", but I don't know for certain.

I should also note that the search API is rate limited differently and as a result, you probably will not be able to make 5000 requests per hour.

Comment: i've heard that the way to get multiple requests is looping through the pages, but I'm not sure how to do that, would you have any insight? (trying to do it on python) also, thank you so much for your help so far !!